# Rotating and absolutely positioning a square of side 50px makes window of sizes less than even 350px horizontally scroll-able. Why does this happen?

Tags: html, css

Increasing rotation increases the size of scroll-able window.

```css
.square {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class = "square"></div>
```

Following is a photo of window

[image]

Comment: it would be hard to say what is causing the issue with only this piece of snippet, the snippet seems to be working fine, can you elaborate on your issue?

Comment: @Jismon Yes,I checked.Apparently the code is working fine in snippet and internet explorer 11 also. But if I open the code directly in google chrome version 67  the scrollbar appears(as shown in image-for small window sizes).Maybe it is a browser specific problem.